# precipitation histogram and line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a monthly precipitation histogram in r using ggplot2 this is the data ideally columns 1 would be the x axis, column 2 would be histogram and column 3 would be line graph

```
Month    MonthlyPrecipitation    30YearNormalPrecipitation 
January                 49.75                         67.1
February                 8.75                         53.6
March                   27                            64.2
April                   55.5                          77.7
May                     62.25                         89.2
June                   171.75                         84.7
July                    50.75                         83.6
August                  37.25                         77.6
September               75.75                         92.6
October                 99.25                         86.3
November                37.25                         90.7
December                43.25                         78.9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created fake data to recreate your example. Month a-l represents January through December. Here you first create a bar plot (I'm assuming that's what you meant by histogram. A true histogram of your data would be flat, given each item in your first variable is unique), then add the line graph. You have to include group = 1 at the end or it will return an error. And in case it wasn't clear, MP is my recreation of monthly precipitation, and NP is 30YearNormalPrecipitation.

```
set.seed(100)

Month <- c(letters[1:12])
MP <- rnorm(12, 50, 5)
NP <- rnorm(12, 80, 5)

df <- data.frame(Month, MP, NP)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Month, y = MP)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', alpha = 0.75) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = NP), colour="blue", group = 1)
```

Comment: You can save a little typing with `geom_col(alpha = 0.75)` instead of `geom_bar(stat = 'identity', alpha = 0.75)`.

Comment: is there specific information that you are supposed to put in rnorm? i put in n, mean and standard deviation and got completely different results than my data.

Comment: You can skip everything before the ggplot line. I just made up a reproducible data set since you didn't provide one. For your data just input:
`ggplot(mydata, aes(x=Month, y = MonthlyPrecipitation)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', alpha = 0.75) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = 30YearNormalPrecipitation), colour="blue", group = 1)`  Where `mydata` is the data set storing your data.

Comment: Just to more directly address your comment/question, you will NOT replicate your original data with rnorm, because the 'r' in rnorm stands for 'random'. You can replicate a call to rnorm by using a specific seed. I've added this to the top of my answer above, so if you were to just run the code above, it should always give the same random normal distribution.

Comment: OK i was not thinking straight until after i signed off for the night. thanks for all your help